# AWS Lambda function deployment using Travis CI with mentioned specific version and alias

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-lambda, travis-ci, continuous-deployment

I'd like to configure continuous deployment process for my AWS Lambda from Github using Travis CI. I see in [Travis CI documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/lambda/) that there is ability to deploy Lambda functions using such syntax (".travis.yml"):

```
deploy:
  provider: lambda
  function_name: "lambda-test"
  region: "us-east-1"
  role: "arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/lambda_basic_execution"
  runtime: "nodejs4.3"
  handler_name: "handler"
```

But I couldn't find any information about deployment to specified AWS Lambda alias and about creation of new AWS Lambda function versions. Does Travis CI provide such functionality at all or there are some other ways to do it?

Comment: just curious why not use serverless on travis.ci side to deploy your lambda after tests?

Comment: @Butuzov I'm not sure that I caught your sought, could you please tell it in more words?

Comment: I was talking about deploying with help of https://serverless.com/ which helps to control all of the required by you options (well except `alias`, haven't worked with lambdas aliases yet). so it's going to be straightforward as you working with travis-ci ... just put the path to a script which will install serverless (node.js), run tests and deploy function if its OK). The syntax of travis config for lambda pretty similar, so it's going to be straightforward for you.

Comment: @Butuzov oh, I don't use serverless framework primarily because my Lambda functions are written on Java (example with nodejs in the question was taken from Travis docs).

Comment: Serverless (node.js) is just a tool to deploy your lambdas. You can write them in anything you want - they will pack it, deploy them to s3, create stack ( cloudformation) with all additional resources.

Comment: @Butuzov that's interesting, thank you for describing! I'll look on it

Comment: No, [_lambda dpl_](https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl/blob/master/lib/dpl/provider/lambda.rb#L71) doesn't currently implement what you asked. However, this is a great feature addition so that [aliases can be created](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/Lambda/Client.html#create_alias-instance_method) when alias option is provided to the _lambda dpl_